# Como hacer una consulta de 2 a mas tablas utilizando PDO

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo, php7

Hola a todos de la comunidad estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar PHP7 con PDO, pero tengo una pequeña duda al momento de realizar una consulta de la DB con 2 tablas no logro a realizar la consulta correcta de esas tablas ayuda por favor. Quiero utilizar INNER JOIN alguien que me ayuda por favor.

```
public function consultas($tabla){

 $consult = Conector::conectando()->prepare("SELECT *
     FROM $tabla det INNER JOIN empleados em ON det.idtalles = em.idemp 
        where det.idtalles = em.idemp
        ORDER BY det.idtalles DESC");

    $consult -> execute();

    return $consult -> fetchAll();

    $consult -> close(); }
```

Cuando aplico el foreach no me realiza la consulta estuve investigando pero no veo mucha información con PDO INNER JOIN que aplican esa técnica solo veo lo normal con msqli. Ayuda por favor.

Comment: Por qué pasas una variable donde debe ir el nombre de la tabla?

Comment: Por ahi pasa la el nombre de la tabla del controlador estoy aprendiendo a Realizar MVC.

Comment: No tienes las tablas relacionadas? Si las tienes relacionadas puedes saltarte el inner join. Yo al tenerlas relacionadas hago `SELECT det.*, em.* FROM $tabla det.nombretabla, em.nombretabla where det.idtalles = em.idem AND det.idtalles = em.idemp ORDER BY det.idtalles DESC` y me tira bastante bien.

Comment: Mis tablas no estan relacionadas seran por eso?

Comment: Puede ser, prueba con la sentencia que puse cambiando nombretabla por el nombre correcto.

Comment: Ahora voy a probar a ver si me jala

Comment: Si lo pruebas y me respondes escribe @Emerita para que  me llegue el mensaje y lo vea, que salgo del curro y no estaré con el pc.

Comment: No me esta funcionando correcto @Emerita ya probé y nada.

Comment: Pues es eso, que no las tienes relacionadas. Tendrán que ver alguien si el join está bien.

Comment: voy a relacionar a ver si me funciona y te aviso.

Comment: Pasar el nombre de una tabla en una consulta preparada no es permitido es decir no se puede bindear

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda a todos ya logre hacer la consulta de las 2 tablas, PDO

Comment: No dejes de escribir la solución y marcar la pregunta como respondida :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Hay una sentencia que esta de más:

```
      where det.idtalles = em.idemp
```

Bastaría con que quedara:

```
SELECT *
FROM $tabla det 
INNER JOIN empleados em ON det.idtalles = em.idemp
ORDER BY det.idtalles DESC
```